# abstract class defining the observer interface

Tags: logging, observer-pattern

I was reading this code for the abstract class defining the interface as :-

```
class Subject;
class Observer {
public:
virtual ~ Observer();
virtual void Update(Subject* theChangedSubject) = 0;//can someone tell what this method    
does
protected:
Observer();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Update()` function should actually be a part of `class Subject` also.
 This must be called at every state change.

The `Subject` should maintain a list of all the `Observers` and call the `Update()` function for all the member `Observers`. This is typically done by holding a pointer / reference of each of the `Observers` and invoking the individual `Update()` functionality implemented by each `Observer`.

And about your question of what this `Update()` function does, it must do what it is expected to do, in the event of a state change.